# Open a new window to show an EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

My question is pertaining to android layout. I would like to open a new window that will display an edit text in the background.

Eg. Clicking on UserName ---> should open a new window that should show a new EditText with an OK and CANCEL button below.

How would I go about this. Should I be changing my Layout.xml or should I be adding some code after the OnClick().

Thanks for your reply !

Comment: ur question is quite vague...do u want to create that window above existing screen ?

Comment: yes Richa I would like to do the same. I would like to grey out the current window and pop-up an EditText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the Alert Dialog Like this

```
 // Add text to dialog
 text = new EditText(this);
 alertDialog.setView(text);          
 alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Your Name");  
 alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     entered_name = text.getText().toString();                                    
     return;  
    }   
 });  
 alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
     return;  
     } 
  }); 
  alertDialog.show();        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you should open a new activity (maybe dialog-styled).

Comment: Adding a new activity is going to use up memory, besides everytime a new pop up needs to be put I don't think starting a new activity would be wise

Answer (score 0):

You can add a theme as `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in your android manifest file and give your activity layout what you want to display.